# Ubuntu gnome-shell decorations / theme broken

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

I've upgraded Ubuntu to 11.04 and replaced unity with gnome shell. Now the controls and window decorations look like if there was "no theme".

I have an ATI HD 3470 and I don't use proprietary drivers (fglrx).

What should I do to get the nice default gnome shell theme?

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-accessibility-themes

sudo apt-get install gnome-themes-standard
```

Then open the Gnome Tweak tool listed above and select Adwaita

Comment: That's it! Works perfectly! Hope @grawity will excuse me for changing the accepted answer to this as this really helped. Thank you.